# Ffmpeg hls live streaming - How to generate shorter segments

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video.js, http-live-streaming

Been using ffmpeg for live streaming via HLS and playing through video.js. It works but there is a 20s delay between the time the stream starts to the time it actually starts playing.

Do you know why ffmpeg command below doesn't create segements that are 3 seconds like I have defined it in the command. The segments tend to be 9s or 10s. Can't get them to a shorter size

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -s 1280x720 -r 30 -i :0.0+nomouse -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -async 30 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -b:a 64k -threads 0 -s 640x360 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 1 -hls_allow_cache 0 /tmp/hls/#{@stream_name}/index.m3u8
```

Here is the m3u8 playlist file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:9
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:10
#EXTINF:8.333333,
index10.ts
#EXTINF:8.333333,
index11.ts
#EXTINF:8.333333,
index12.ts
#EXTINF:8.333333,
index13.ts
#EXTINF:2.366667,
index14.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: Question: what is hls_list_size for in your case - does it work? I tried to use it for what I believe is its intended use, but it does not seem to work. I set it to like 5, and expect max 5 .ts files to exist on disk. But it just keep on adding files up forever, running out of disk space...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must also specify the keyframe interval. Also known as the GOP (group of pictures) size.

`-g [time]`

Comment: Before using -g I used -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" but I don't understand why it didn't work