# How to decrease latency for hls nginx rtmp?

Tags: nginx, rtmp, http-live-streaming

This hls file generate by live streamer:

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-VERSION:3
 #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
 #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
 #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
 #EXTINF:8.033,
  mys-0.ts
 #EXTINF:3.367,
 mys-1.ts
 #EXTINF:8.333,
 mys-2.ts
  #EXTINF:7.934,
 mys-3.ts
 #EXTINF:8.333,
 mys-4.ts
```

How to decrease duration of one file ts? I try to set nginx config: hls_fragment 3;  hls_playlist_length 30;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ffmpeg hls live streaming - How to generate shorter segments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906259/ffmpeg-hls-live-streaming-how-to-generate-shorter-segments)

Comment: You can use ffplayer with nobuffer to test the latency, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45370210/6521116)