# ffmpeg splits video with differents segments size

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, split

im trying to split a video in segments with same lenght using ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -y -i teste.mp4 -map 0 -segment_time 10 -f segment -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -crf 24 -tune film -vf "drawtext=text='teste':start_number=0:x=0:y=0" -an teste\out%d.mp4
```

the input file is 3minutes

in the output folder i get several files each have a duration between 8 and 13 seconds.

during the process i get many messages like

```
Past duration 0.994987 too large
Past duration 0.998329 too large
Past duration 0.995995 too large
Past duration 0.997993 too large
Past duration 0.998665 too large
Past duration 0.999321 too large
```

also the output file are not printing the "teste" drawtext filter...

does anyone know what is the problem?

how can a really force ffmpeg to split 10 seconds segment (i can accept 9 or 8 seconds segments as an "error margin" but get 13 seconds segments asking for 10 is something really wrong to me)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ffmpeg hls live streaming - How to generate shorter segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906259/ffmpeg-hls-live-streaming-how-to-generate-shorter-segments)